# How to plot two or more equations simultaneously?

Tags: plotting

I have this two equations, and I want to solve them in a graphical way.

[image]

So, -I'm thinking- how can I plot them at the same time?

Comment: Read the help articles on ContourPlot and Solve. They will show you the way.

Comment: `Plot[{3-2x, (4-x)/3},{x,0,1}]`?

Comment: Thanks.  If I have equations with more than one variable, how can I set the range for each variable.  I mean in this case you propose for x range ,{x,0,1}; what happen if I have x, y, z, etc?

Comment: The option `PlotRange` can be used to set the range for both variables.

Comment: does `ContourPlot[{2 x + y - 3 == 0, x + 3 y == 4}, {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 3},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
 MeshFunctions -> {Boole[2 # + #2 == 3 && (# + 3 #2 == 4)] &}, 
 Mesh -> {{1}},
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.8, .9}]]` work in your version?

Comment: Yes it does... Do you know how can I make it visible the "solution point" in the graph with its values?

Answer (score 2):

```
pt = {x, y} /. Solve[{2 x + y - 3 == 0, x + 3 y == 4}, {x, y}][[1]]

(* {1, 1} *)

Legended[
 ContourPlot[
  {2 x + y - 3 == 0, x + 3 y == 4},
  {x, -1, 3}, {y, -1, 3},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, y}),
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[pt]}],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[
   {ColorData[97][1], ColorData[97][2]},
   {2 x + y - 3 == 0, x + 3 y == 4}], {.7, .7}]]
```

[image]